# Installing Bleachbit on Centos 8

Tags: centos, package-management

Thank you for the HOWTO  you posted on how to install Bleachbit on Centos 8. When I try to install `gobject-introspection-devel` it returns `No match for argument`

Can you please give us a work around it ?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Could you please add a link to the HOWTO you mentioned? Also, you seem to be addressing someone in particular. However, it is customary to address the site's community in general as you never know who will respond ...

Answer (score 0):

Bleachbit depend on python2. python2 is [deprecated (EOL)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0373/) that's why it is not installed by default on Centos8. The up and coming Bleachbit4 will be supported in Centos8.

[BleachBit Documentation:](https://docs.bleachbit.org/doc/install-on-linux.html)

> Requirements
>
> BleachBit version 2.2 required Python 2.7 and GTK version 2. It did not support Python 2.5, Python 2.7, Python 3, or GTK 3.
>
> BleachBit 3 requires GTK 3 and Python 2.7.
>
> BleachBit 4 (coming soon) will require GTK 3 and Python 3.

[Python2: Maintenance releases](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0373/#maintenance-releases)

> Being the last of the 2.x series, 2.7 received bugfix support until 2020. Support officially stopped January 1 2020, and 2.7.18 code freeze occurred on January 1 2020, but the final release will occur after that date.
>
> Planned future release dates:
>
> - 2.7.18 release candidate early April, 2020
> - 2.7.18 mid-April, 2020

Answer (score 0):

You can find [bleachbit for CentOS 8](https://extras.getpagespeed.com/redhat/8/noarch/repoview/bleachbit.html) in a *commercial* repository by GetPageSpeed.

Although if you just want to clear up some disk space, you can do with some [basic commands to clean up disk space](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/clear-disk-space-centos), e.g. trimming excessively large log files:

```
find /var -name "*.log" \( \( -size +50M -mtime +7 \) -o -mtime +30 \) -exec truncate {} --size 0 \;
```